# Search for >$(bla)< and replace

Tags: powershell, finalbuilder

I must replace a value in a file. This works for normal text with this command

```
(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "SEARCH", "REPLACE"} | Set-Content $file
```

But now, the search text is "$(SEARCH)" (without quotes). Backslash escaping the '$' with '`$' doesn't work:

```
(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`$(SEARCH)", "BLA"} | Set-Content $file
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `'` instead of `"` to disable expansion?

Answer (score 2):

The `-replace` operator is actually a [regular expression replacement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) not a simple string replacement, so you've got to escape the regular expression:

```
(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '\$\(SEARCH\)', "BLA"} | Set-Content $file
```

Note that you can suppress string interpolation by using single quotes (') of double quotes (") around string literals, which I've done above.

Comment: Or better yet, `$_ -replace [regex]::escape('$(SEARCH)'), 'REPLACE'` since a lot of people aren't aware of how to properly escape a regex statement.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Or another option is string's Replace method: `$_.Replace('$(Search)', "BLA")`.

Comment: @Joey Sure there is. `$` is an anchor to a line ending. You have to escape it unless it appears inside a character set.

Comment: Ouch, I shouldn't comment before first tea in the morning. You're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

Macintron,

You can try something like below :

```
(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_.replace('$(SEARCH)', "BLA"} | Set-Content $file
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly (or even more) faster

```
sc $file ((gc $file -Raw) -replace '\$\(search\)','BLAHH')
```